# How to encode Query String in JS and decode in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, decoding

My JS function has this code:

```js
window.location = 'example.php?id=' + id + '&amount=' + amount;
```

The result in the browser's address bar (for example) is:

> example.php?id=5&amount=45

I want to encode all the query string, including variable names and its values. Is that even posible or should I just encode the values?

At this moment I'm just encoding the values using

```js
btoa(id);
```

And getting the values in PHP using:

```
base64_decode($_GET['id`]);
```

The result is:

> id=OQ==

But I want to encode the variable name as well, if it's possible

**EDIT**
I want to encode the variable names in order to make them unreadable to the user

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Numbers don't need to be URL encoded.

Comment: If you encode the keys & values, you'll also need to `encodeURIComponent()` the whole thing before appending it to the URL, because base64 may contain `=` signs which may otherwise be considered key/value separators

Comment: Why encode the variable names too?  What problem are you trying to solve?  You could potentially serialize your data into a custom format, base64-encode (and url-encode of course) that whole blob, and have a single query string value containing that blob.  But what's the driving reason behind all this?

Comment: @blex How can I decode the URI in PHP. I tried it before, comments says PHP decode all the $_GET by default, but I could make it work

Comment: You just need to `encodeURIComponent()` in the front-end, and PHP will automatically decode them for you, no need to URI decode them on the PHP side. If you edit your question to include what code you have now (on both the front-end and the back-end), maybe we'll be able to see what's wrong

Comment: Regarding your edit, please note that you might make it harder to see for a regular user, but someone with a bit of knowledge can easily decode that string. Hiding information like that doesn't make it secure.

Comment: @Poble Yes, that's what that does. If you want multiple keys, you may want to create a helper function to make the rest of the code simpler. Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3zkf197s/). Then, PHP will see two indexes: `aWQ=` (`id`) and `YW1vdW50` (`amount`). But yes, anybody who has seen base64 in their life will know that it's base64 and that they can just `atob` them to decode them

Comment: @blex I tried `uri = encodeURIComponent('id=' + id + '&amount=' + amount);`and send it using `window.lcoation = 'index.php?' + uri;` In the PHP side, I cannot get the values, instead, my $_GET only have 1 position, which key name is the exact value of `'id=' + id + '&amount=' + amount'`

Comment: @Poble Did you see my last comment?